# How to deny permission to create resources in Azure except some users

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Is there any  in built role to deny permission to create resources in az subscription except some users. I.

I have used 'not allowed resources types' policy but it applies to whole subscription.

Comment: for users you don't allow them to [create resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/rbac-and-directory-admin-roles#azure-roles) you can assign `Reader` role. Is it what you want?

Answer (score 0):

**I Tried to reproduce the same in my environment to deny the resource creation in Azure:**

Thanks to **Tiny Wang** for suggesting the same.

1. Assign **Reader** role to **Users** or **Group** for restricting resource creation in **Azure**, like below.

**Azure Portal > Subscription > Select your subscription > Access control (IAM) > Add > Add role assignment.**

[image]

**Reader** role assigned.

[image]

When I tried to create **Azure VM** within **Subscription**, I got an authorization error with the same user.

[image]

> Note: if you create an Azure policy to deny the resource creation, the policy will apply to the scope level, not to users.

```
Ex: Subscription, Resource Groups
```

[image]

I have created a policy and assigned it to the resource group scope to deny resource creation within a resource group.

When I tried to create any resource, I got a policy restriction error.

[image]

**Azure Policy rule:**

```
{
"mode": "All",
"policyRule": {
"if": {
"field": "type",
"in": "[parameters('listOfResourcesTypesNotAllowed')]"
},
"then": {
"effect": "Deny"
}
},
"parameters": {
"listOfResourcesTypesNotAllowed": {
"type": "Array",
"metadata": {
"displayName": "Not Allowed Resources creation",
"description": "The list of resources type that cannot be deployed.",
"strongType": "resourceTypes"
}
}
}
}
```